# How can I exclude a folder from a command line backup

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, backup

I'm doing a command line backup of the file system with `bin/magento setup:backup --code`,

but I have one directory which contains a lot of large image files that I would like to exclude.

Is there a way to configure my file system backups to **exclude a directory**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento module named `module-backup` having such feature.
You can add the directory which you would like to ignore in the following file.

1. `<magento-root>\vendor\magento\module-backup\Helper\Data.php`
2. Look for the method named `getBackupIgnorePaths` in `Data.php`
3. After the below line:

   `$this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR)->getAbsolutePath('report'),`

add below line of code and replace directory of your choice. I have assumed
`<magento-root>\pub\large_image` directory.

```
$this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::PUB)->getAbsolutePath('large_image'),
```

Take directory constants (`DirectoryList::PUB` or `DirectoryList::VAR_DIR`) from the `<magento-root>\vendor\magento\framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList.php`

As this is public function so you can make override by adding plugin into this. Do not make direct any changes in the **vendor** directory.